# Using jQuery to update a span element with form input data but its not updating

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an h2 element which has styled content (css) inside this I also have a span element called highlight. I want to update this with a text input on the submit button being clicked.

the result I get (on click) is the original text clears out, then is refreshed into the span again so it still shows "John Smith".

```
//index.html
<span id="highlight">John Smith</span>
<form action="" class="form-inline">
   <input id="name" type="text" placeholder="Enter name" size="35">
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="button-btn">
</form>

//app.js 
$(function(){
    let name = $('#name').val();
    $('.button-btn').click(function(){
        $('#highlight').text(name);
    });
});
```

Its getting frustrating as I think I am doing it right, but obviously not. Thank you in advance for a resolution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is you are taking the value of the input element on page load and the value is empty. You should take the value from the input inside the click event handler function:

```js
$(function(){
  console.log($('#name').val() === ""); //true
  $('.button-btn').click(function(e){
    let name = $('#name').val();
    $('#highlight').text(name);
    e.preventDefault(); // prevented the submission of the form for demo
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="highlight">John Smith</span>
<form action="" class="form-inline">
   <input id="name" type="text" placeholder="Enter name" size="35">
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="button-btn">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. works great! not sure about e.preventDefault() but will google it

Comment: @Jones, you are most welcome, I have added that for demo purpose to stay on the same page, you can find more on that ....https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Comment: Thank you helped greatly. My functionality is working great.